# Interview puzzle on traveling on a line segment

Tags: algorithm

Here's an interesting question I came upon:

Let's just say on a number line of length `M`, where `0 < M <= 1,000,000,000`, you given `N` (`1 < N <= 100,000`) integer pairs of points. In each pair, the first point represents where an object is currently located, and the second point represents where an object should be moved. (Keep in mind the `second` point may be *smaller* than the `first`).

Now, assume you start at the point `0` and have a cart that can hold `1` object. You want to move all objects from their initial positions to their respective final positions while traveling the least distance along the number line (*not* displacement). You have to end up on point `M`.

Now, I've been trying to reduce this problem to a simpler problem. To be honest I can't even think of a brute force (*possibly* greedy) solution. However, my first thought was to degenerate a backwards movement to two forward movements, but that doesn't seem to work in all cases.

I drew out these `3` sample test cases in [image]

The answer to the first testcase is `12`. First, you pick up the `red` item at point `0`. Then you move to point `6` (distance = `6`), drop the `red` item temporarily, then pick up the `green` item. Then you move to point `5` (distance = `1`) and drop the `green` item. Then you move back to point `6` (distance = `1`) and pick up the `red` item you dropped, move to point 9 (distance = `3`), then move to point `10` (distance = `1`) to finish off the sequence.

The total distance traveled was `6 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 = 12`, which is the minimum possible distance.

The other two cases have answers of `12`, I believe. However, I can't find a general rule to solve it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please don't ask off-topic questions.

Comment: @Oded the lack of the "interview question" tag doesn't make this off-topic

Comment: @BlackBear - it being a purely mathematical question, does. What's the programming specific aspect here?

Comment: @Oded- There are many interview questions here that ask about algorithm design.  I suspect that most of those are on-topic, and under that assumption I would think this question is on-topic as well.  The FAQ says that "software algorithms" are OK here, and this appears to be a software algorithm question.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't you need a datastructure to count the "overlap"? Otherwise I'm solving it the wrong way.

Comment: And I tried to tag it with "interview-question" but apparently that tag doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @templatetypedef - This is a general algorithm. There is no aspect of programming to it. The algorithm questions that are on topic here are those that deal with implementing them. I would think this question would have a better home on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missunderstanding the problem but what about the following:

1. Sort the pairs by the first number of the pair which is the current
   location
2. Move along the line swapping elements to their proper location (you
   have a temp variable)

The fact that it is sorted guarantees that you don't go back and forth the elements to place them in the proper location (regardless if the line is represented as an array or list)

**Update after @templatetypedef comment:**
Use a `HashTable` to store all the pairs. Use the current location of each pair as index key.
Use a second index over the pairs.

```
 1. Get next pair according to index from the line.
 2. If current pair exists in hashtable then place element to its target location.  
    2.a Remove pair from hashtable.  
    2.b Make current pair the target location. Then go to step 1  
 ELSE 
        Increment current index until you get a pair present in the hashtable. Go to step 2
```

Comment: You can only move one unit at a time, so many times you have to retrace your path I think

Comment: I don't really follow you.It seems that the requirement is just to move forward and swap numbers.You already know the current location and the target location.Just swap them (using the cart variable as you say it) and move to the next pair

Comment: Consider this counterexample: (1, 10), (10, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4).  The optimal way to do this would be to carry object 1 to position 10, then pick up the object at position 10 and carry it to position 1, then to carry the 2 to the 3 and the 3 to the 4.  Doing this in sorted order of starting position would carry the 1 to the 10, then back all the way up to the start to carry the 2 to the 3, the 3 to the 4, then go all the way to the end to pick up the 10 and bring it back.

Comment: @templatetypedef:I see what you mean.Updated answer

Comment: In your updated answer, does the "current index" just indicate the current position?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are given these moves `(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), ...` then the minimum distance you have to travel is `abs(b - a) + abs(d - c) + abs(f - e) + ...` and the actual distance you travel is `abs(b - a) + abs(c - b) + abs(d - c) + abs(e - d) + ...`.
Basically, given an array of moves the point is to minimize the "travel distance" function by swapping elements around. If you consider a particular combination as a node and all the combinations you can reach from it as edges you can use one of the many graph search algorithms around which make use of an  heuristic. One example is the [beam search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search).

Answer (score 0):

[This is the asymmetric traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem). You can think of this as a graph. The edges will be each (start, finish) pair, one for each (0, start), and all other pairs of (finish, start).

Assuming NP!=P, it will have an exponential expected running time.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  This is a *special case* of asymmetric TSP, so it might have a polynomial-time solution.

Comment: Don't you need an edges like (finish, M), where `M` is the endpoint of the number line?

Comment: Also, an exponential algorithm is way too slow, for `N` can be 100,000.